# include, path, I can come out of this

Tags: php, path, include

As many users suggested me I created a file `globals.php` where I:

```
<?php
    define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
?>
```

and then I include this file on every file of the site.

But now the problem comes when I include this file on the other files.

E.g. site structure:

```
/en/index.php
/header.php
/globals.php
```

Now when I include `header.php` on `index.php`

```
<?php
//header.php
include 'globals.php';

//index.php
include '../globals.php';
include '../header.php';
?>
```

And now `header.php` cannot find `globals.php'` because it search for `'../globals.php'`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use absolute paths, instead of relative ones?

Comment: It not advides to use `<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>`
Should I always write e.g.: `__DIR__'./../globals.php`;

Comment: And then when I have two times `'../../'`?

Comment: It would be easiest to just use absolute paths, so if you are on a unix/linux server, something like this: `include '/var/www/globals.php';`

Comment: ok. But then when I'm developing on `'/var/dev/dev/'` and move all to `'/var/www/'` nothing is working anymore...

Comment: That means there is either an error, probably due to the new directory setup, or it's a server permissions issue.

Comment: If I use `include '/var/www/globals.php';` this is ok only for that server and for that absolute path. So what if the absolute path changes?

Comment: If the path to the PHP file changes, then you have to update the code accordingly. The `/var/www/` prefix is standard for *nix servers and shouldn't change unless you are nesting things in a sub folder of the main web server.

Comment: Yes but this is not a permanently and flexible solution...
What about `include __DIR__.'../globals.php'`?

Comment: The `__DIR__` constant just equates to the directory the current PHP script is executing in, which changes based on which script you are including the file in.

Comment: Are you shure? Doesn't seem to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets Imagine that your globals.php file is in a config directory from your document rood

So you have

```
/index.php
/config/globals.php
```

A good approach may be to include the globals.php via  `require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/config/globals.php);` this will work regardless of what directory you are in your sight.

For my personal preference I like to set a constant up for the root of my project and pull all of the project relevant data from there, for example

```
if (!defined("APP_ROOT")) define("APP_ROOT", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

You may want to evaluate that as an option as your starting point as opposed to **DIR**.

I find it much more natural...

If I need to include a file I would navigate to view http://www.mysite.com/library/database.php then I just `include(APP_ROOT."/library/database.php");`;

Another goodie that may work out for you is to include a

```
SetEnv APP_CONFIG_FILE "/path/to/config/file.php"
```

directive in your .htaccess file then in all of your scripts just

`include($_SERVER["APP_CONFIG_FILE"]);`

Comment: The only problem I see is that if I develop my site on another placed than the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, then it will not work, and I'll have to change all the file where `if(!defined...` is written

Comment: that's why you define a constant as opposed to using $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] everywhere... like if your development environment you hide behind a directory ie localhost/sitename/ then you just update your constant to reflect that done.

Comment: ok I define this constant `define("APP_ROOT", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);` on `globals.php`. My problem is when I have to include `globals.php` on the files! Because if a file is included on another file I have always the same problem of the `current working directory`

Comment: how about this then ... in your main site directory (docroot on live or whatever on dev) you add to the .htaccess  `SetEnv GLOBAL_CONFIG_PATH "/path/to/the/config/global.php"` Then in your individual php files you so require_once($ENV["GLOBAL_CONFIG_PATH"]);

Comment: Wow this is a good idea! Thank you. Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: try `getenv("GLOBAL_CONFIG_PATH")` depending on the apache config ENV might not be getting populated by php

Comment: Isn't $_SERVER['GLOBAL_CONFIG_PATH'] fine? Ok with getenv I get the env var

Comment: Should be ...  i guess that's where env variable get put now a days

Comment: With getenv("...") I get the var. Is rather to use getenv?

Comment: getenv is probably safer if you move between hosts. I know once upon a time I have seen $_ENV populated with environment variables, I don't know what server config or version of php change to led to it being placed in the SERVER superglobal array but getenv should get it in all cases

Comment: I read that $_SERVER[] is better. I set the name of the env var on my language so there is no problem in the future if they add others strings to $_SERVER!
Here is the link: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/difference-between-server-and-getenv-248870.html

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that "header.php" is in the same directory as the "globals.php" as thus you could do something like this for the "header.php"

```
<?php
//header.php
include 'globals.php'
?>
```

And that should do the work and if it still doesn't work, please comment it out.

Thanks.

Comment: No because when `header.php` is included on `/en/index.php` the working directory is `/en/` so `globals.php` will not be founded anymore!

Comment: Ohhhh! I've think I've got it bro. Try this now >> <?php include '../globals.php' ?>

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to edit the "head.php" file's include statement as well too. Get it bro?

Comment: Umm, yeaps. But this is the only solution which you might want to do OR you want to include a common "navigational panel" which comes from another PHP file.